# using methods within Linq projection

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following code :

```
        var EmployeeXPosition = from emp in context.WTDEmployee
                                from ep in emp.WTDEmployeeXOXPosition
                                select new { 
                                    EmployeeId = emp.id, 
                                    FullNameAndPosition =  string.Format("{0} {1} : {2}", emp.FirstName, emp.LastName, ep.WTDPosition.Position) 
                                };
```

It gives the error :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method 'System.String
>   Format(System.String, System.Object,
>   System.Object, System.Object)' method,
>   and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

Sure enough I could do :

```
 emp.FirstName+" "+ emp.LastName +" : " + ep.WTDPosition.Position
```

But it just looks ugly, any suggestions on how to use `string.Format` instead ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually solve this by creating two statements - one in LinqToEntities (or ToSql, or whatever) and then another in LinqToObjects.  I do what I need to do in the store, and then do a separate processing step with the objects in memory.  This mixes the best of both worlds.

```
 var EmployeeXPosition = from emp in context.WTDEmployee
                                from ep in emp.WTDEmployeeXOXPosition
                                select new { 
                                    emp.id, 
                                    emp.FirstName, 
                                    emp.LastName,
                                    ep.WTDPosition.Position
                                };

var result = from item in EmployeeXPosition.ToList()
             select new 
             {
                EmployeeId = item.id, 
                FullNameAndPosition =  string.Format("{0} {1} : {2}", item.FirstName, item.LastName, item.Position) 
             };
```

Answer (score 1):

[This codeplex project](http://linqexprprojection.codeplex.com/) claims to do exactly what you want.
Unfortunately I don't have time to try it now - but here's what they say

> LINQ Expression Projection library provides tool that enable using
>   lambda expressions in LINQ projections (to anonymous and predefined
>   types) even if the lambda expression is not defined in the query but
>   rather is stored in a variable or retrieved via a function or
>   property.